# How to handle edits to your answer that alter or expand on the information it contains?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, etiquette

Basic editing for typos and code formatting are great!

But recently, I've had two types of edits that I was not sure how to handle:

1. They *completely* changed my code example.
2. They added additional suggestions to my answer.

What is the appropriate way to handle these types of edits?

As an example of (1), the OP asked how to do x with numbers. I pasted sample code (with a link to a github) that showed how to do x with objects and suggested they could extrapolate. Someone changed my entire example to do x with numbers. Now I'm sure this helped the OP, but was no longer my example nor did it then match the provided github reference.

As an example of (2), I provided several suggested techniques for achieving y. Someone added an edit with several more techniques.

In the first case, it seems like it would have been better for the person editing my post to provide their own answer instead of completely rewriting mine.

In the second case, I think comments would have been more appropriate. Adding someone else's thoughts/suggestions in my post implies to me that those are my suggestions.

How should these types of edits be handled?

Comment: From your description of the edits, it sounds like they should be rolled back.

Comment: Rolling back is probably appropriate. Still, a link to the actual edits/revisions would come handy.

Comment: Is there a place we can explain *why* we rolled back their edits and keep things friendly?

Comment: Yep - [you can edit from the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41953/could-we-be-permitted-to-provide-a-reason-for-rolling-back) and describe the reason for the rollback (this is also useful if you want to keep *some* but not *all* changes). You can also address an editor by name via a comment on the post (for example, since I've edited this question you could notify me of a comment by including `@Shog9` in a comment.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's your post - your name is under it, folks are going to expect you to be in some sense responsible for what it says. So the critical question here is...

**Are *you* happy with the changes that were made?**

If you think the post is better with the edits, then keep the changes; if you think it's worse, roll it back. You have **real, ultimate power** here - if the edit was suggested, [you can even alter the outcome of the review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions/295028#295028) and make it so that the editor doesn't get credit for an approved edit.

Editing is a pretty fundamental part of how these sites operate. It's expected that authors will be welcoming of edits that make real improvements to their posts - but that doesn't mean they have to accept *all* changes. Try to evaluate the changes fairly, and reject them if you honestly believe the post is poorer for having them.

### See also: [In Defense of Editing](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/08/in-defense-of-editing/)

Comment: An interesting read, thanks! For me its weighing the difference between substantially changing what I meant and providing a better answer. If it is doing both of those things ... then it is better as another answer ... not an edit to mine. But I'm not sure that matches with the purpose of edits here.

Comment: It's subjective; there's nothing stopping anyone from posting a competing answer, but some folks prefer collaboration if what they're contributing is substantially similar to an existing answer. Heck, I've even been known to delete my own answer in favor of contributing edits to a later answer if I think the later author does a better job of explaining the matter! I think it's best to leave these decisions to the author and editor - if they want to work together, they can; if one or both aren't comfortable doing that, they can each have their own answer.

Comment: I guess I lean toward "my name on the bottom ... my thoughts in the post" and see editing like a good tech editor ... correcting but never substantially changing the content ... even if they could explain it better or have a better example. A truly collaborative post should have all participants names attached.

Comment: Well, they're always all listed in the revision history. But I do agree we could improve the UI there; still, there's no hard rule about it - it boils down to what you, as an author, are willing to work with.

Answer (score 4):

As Shog9 noted, you always have the option of rolling back any edits you disagree with.  It's your post, with your name below it, and that gives you pretty wide latitude in deciding what you want it to say.

That said, let's assume that you *don't* think the edits should be simply reverted, but you also disagree with some aspects of them, or are uncomfortable with having your name attached to them.  In that case, you have several options:

- In the first example you mentioned, one option would be to edit the answer to include *both* code examples.  You can even add a note attributing the second version to the editor, if you like.
- In the second example, consider whether you *would* recommend those options, now that you know about them.  If yes, feel free to keep them in your answer (and maybe edit them further).  If not, just remove them (and/or follow one of the suggestions below).

  (Note that, while it's perfectly OK to suggest improvements to an answer via comments, ideally they should not *stay* in comments only.  If they're good suggestions, they should be incorporated into the answer, or turned into a separate answer.  If they're bad, they should just be deleted.  [Comments are meant to be temporary,](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) even if they often tend to linger around in practice.)
- If you'd prefer to keep your answer as you originally wrote it, but think that the edited version could be a decent alternative answer, you can always (revert the edit and) leave a comment to the editor saying so.  [You can @ping any user who edited a post in a comment below it,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) even if the autocompletion menu doesn't show their username.
- If you think that an answer you wrote *should* become a collaborative effort, you can always [mark it as Community Wiki.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)  One of the effects of doing so is that your name will no longer be shown as prominently under it (and may not be shown at all, if someone else makes enough edits to it).
- You could even combine the previous two options and post the edited solution yourself as a separate Community Wiki answer after reverting your own answer to its original form.  That can be good choice especially if the edit was suggested by an anonymous visitor, making it unlikely that they'll repost it as a separate answer themselves.  Just include a note in the CW answer stating where it comes from (preferably with a link to your answer's edit history or, if the edit was suggested and reviewed, to the review task).

Comment: Great suggestions! Your first suggestion would have worked perfectly in my case ... keeping my answer but also showing the alternative code. I'll keep these in mind for next time.